# how to find total sum of nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to find sum of only first nested array?

```
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
```

I tried using map with reduce method.
but it is returning both nested array's sum individually.

```
arr.map((value, i) => value.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr,0));

output- [6,15]
```

But i want only first nested array sum.

```
so it should be [[6],[4,5,6]];
```

Comment: Put an if statement around the reduce?

Comment: just change arr[0] without running any loop?

Comment: `arr[0] = [arr[0].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr,0)];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think This Should Work:

```
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
];

let newArray = arr.map((value, i) => {
  if (i === 0) {
    return [value.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)];
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Output:

```
[[6],[4,5,6]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to modify first index why iterate over all the values using map reduce?

```
arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
]

arr[0] = [arr[0].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)]

arr will return [[6],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: Yeah it also works.

Comment: Thank you. If you use this solution i.e. updating arr[0] you can save on unnecessary lookups to rest of the array.